# How would I change this from two hardcoded images to an array of images.

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, gsap

I copied this Pen a while back and had it on my list and finally come to it now. However my knowledge is kind of rusty and i'm a little stuck right now trying to change it from two hardcoded images to a dynamic array of images.

Here is the [Pen](https://codepen.io/nhekkens/pen/JBEdEJ)

I tried adding

```js
var slide3 = new Slide(width, height, 'middle');
    var l3 = new THREE.ImageLoader();
    l3.setCrossOrigin('Anonymous');
    l3.load('/assets/ScreenSaver/space3.jpg', function(img) {
        slide3.setImage(img);
    })
        
    root.scene.add(slide3);
```

But that wont cut it, it seems i need to add another control variable.

Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: this is a pretty sweet pen, do you know it's origins?

Comment: @pailhead here is the [link] (https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/details/PNXbGo)

Answer (score 1):

Ended using this, someone achieved this in react and lucky for me i also have the same objective.

[Solution](https://codepen.io/clindsey/details/xrQJEz)

```
loadNextImages (images, index) {
let first = index
let second
const tmp = (first + 1) % (images.length)
if (index % 2 === 0) {
  second = tmp
} else {
  second = first
  first = tmp
}
this.slide0.setImage(images[first])
this.slide1.setImage(images[second])
return tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

To add another slide, try this:

```
      var slide3 = new Slide(width, height, 'in');
  var l3 = new THREE.ImageLoader();
    l3.setCrossOrigin('Anonymous');
    l3.load('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-5w-Kdidn-qT7gkRKDgQzFmCULZQN-YvwFchCenzPVIkggTif1Q', function(img) {
        slide3.setImage(img);
    })

root.scene.add(slide3);
  tl.add(slide3.transition(), 0);
```

You missed the last line. Check it working with an extra image here:

https://codepen.io/pmbranco/pen/gdBmyR

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping first of all. I did miss out the line on the question but actually did put it in the code. If you watch your example you will notice it uses slide1 between the animation. I would like the following behaviour: Show Slide 1 ( use 1 and 2 for animation ) Show Slide 2 ( use 2 and 3 for animation ) Show Slide 3 ( reset, ideally 3 too 1 )

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to create a variable that is an array where each element is the image source, and then load them in dynamically. That way you only need to write that chunk out once. Each time you want to add a new image, take one out, or edit the order, you only need to edit the image array.

```html
var images = ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/winter.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/spring.jpg'];
  
for (let x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
  var slide[x] = new Slide(width, height, 'out');
  var l[x] = new THREE.ImageLoader();
  l[x].setCrossOrigin('Anonymous');
  l[x].load(images[x], function(img) {
    slide.setImage(img);
  })
  root.scene.add(slide);

  tl.add(slide[x].transition(), 0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, did you try adding this to the pen? I added it and it gave an error. Also please test it with three images as I think there is alot more to the answer than this. I would like the following behaviour: Show Slide 1 ( use 1 and 2 for animation ) Show Slide 2 ( use 2 and 3 for animation ) Show Slide 3 ( reset, ideally 3 too 1 ). As the above code would fix the array issue ( thanks again ) but it wouldn't fix the issue of its only made to do two slide ( back and forth )